# how can I get the value of static initialised global variables from ELF file?

Tags: elf, objdump, readelf

For example I have following c++ source file

```cpp
// define global variables here
int Label = 1234;
char Hash[] = "0x11231abc";
```

compile this to *.o file, and may be later linked to an executable binary. Is it possible to get the value from ELF file by using some existing tools, like readelf, objdump?

Comment: I think using pythoin ELF tool can achieve this goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the value from ELF file by using some existing tools, like readelf, objdump?

Whether this is possible *at all* depends on how exactly these variables are used, whether they are local or global, whether they have their address taken, which compiler is used and what optimizations are in effect.

If the variables are global and the code is not optimized, sure some combination of `readelf` and `objdump` commands could possibly get you the answer.

In general, GDB would be a better tool to use here.